# Firefox renders checkbox input type as textbox

Tags: html, firefox

I put a checkbox in a form's th element and it displays as a text input Firefox (currently version 25), although it renders correctly as a checkbox in all other browsers (even IE8!).

I looked at the inspector, the type attribute on the element is being immediately preceded by `&#160;` which is causing it to render as a text input instead of a checkbox.

I opened the View Source, there's nothing out of the ordinary - the whitespaces are normal whitespaces, not non-breaking whitespaces.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: show your code or make a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being with the combination of Firefox and using [jqWidont](http://davecardwell.co.uk/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery-widont/).

I've got jqWidont applied to all table headers, and on Firefox it's inserting non-breaking spaces inside the child elements (only sometimes, I'm not sure what elements/attributes are affected).

Here's a jsFiddle showing the behaviour (view in Firefox): http://jsfiddle.net/4ZZnW/

Html:

```
<p>Checkbox: <input type="checkbox"/></p> <p class="widont">Checkbox: <input type="checkbox"/></p>
```

Script:

```
$(".widont").widont();
```

My solution was to be more choosy about when to use jqWidont on my elements and not use it when there are child elements.